# Read a file that was created

Tags: c#

I have created a file now I want to read it back into the program.When I click button2 I want it to read the file and display it in label6.text

```
public void writetext()
    {

        using (TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("filename.txt"))

        {
         writer.WriteLine("First name, {0} Lastname, {1} Phone,{2} Day of birth,{3} Month of Birth{4}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, maskedTextBox1.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text);
         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("First Name,{0} Lastname, {1} Phone,{2} Day of birth,{3} Month of Birth{4}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, maskedTextBox1.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text)); 
        }


    }
    public void reset()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        maskedTextBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(); 
     }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
        label6.Text = ("filename.text");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File.ReadAllLines(filename) will return a string[] (one string for each line) - in your code you aren't storing the returned string[] from ReadAllLines().  Also, ReadAllLines() will close the stream for you I believe.

Without making design suggestions on what you have, you would need to do something like this to get what you want:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
label6.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

That would join the array of lines separated by the newline character appropriate for your region.  It then assigns the result string to the label.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
label6.Text = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
```

[ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) returns the entire file as a string.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Comment: @RandyWhite30, you need to join them.

Comment: Not sure what you guys are talking about.

Comment: he commented on the wrong answer I think.  The answer after yours is incorrect and says to pass the result of ReadAllLines() to the Text property on the Label. You suggestion is what should be used.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks, but I have to give it to you for explaining the NewLine issue. If the file came from a Unix or Mac, then you'd need to make sure that lines are converted to `\r\n` on a Windows form.

Answer (score 0):

In button2_Click() event, after reading all lines from file, you need to save those lines in some string and then assign that string to label.Text property or directly assing it to text property.

Label.Text= File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) you can find more info about File.ReadAllLines() method.

You can use File.ReadAllText() method. It gets all text in one single string.

Comment: ReadAllLines returns an array of string, so this won't compile.

Comment: @Jordan, thanks for correcting. We can use ReadAllText() method instead of ReadAllLines() method.